# Swift: Table with cells (same properties different content; clickable )

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I need to create a table with 50 rectangular cells and:
All of the cells must have the same properties but different contents;
Each cell has to be clickable;
Cells must have different items inside of them (images, labels etc).
I started programming recently and I'm 16 so please don't bite my head off if I wasn't clear or whatever...

By the way I tried to create a table view with custom cells but I'm not sure it's working, plus I'm in landscape mode so maybe I need to create them programmatically... Can you just please tell me if I'm doing it right using the custom cells and maybe give me some advice or send me some tutorials for these things I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. Go ahead in your achieve. Here are some examples for you.

Your ViewController

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let tableReuseIdentifier = "TableCell"    

    let tableView: UITableView! = {
        let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: UITableViewStyle.grouped)
        table.backgroundColor = .clear
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        table.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        table.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        return table
    }()
    var items: [U]? = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        //registering your customCell into tableView
        self.tableView!.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tableReuseIdentifier)
    }

    public func setupViews() {
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items?.count ?? 0
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: MyCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

        //here you can manipulate some data to insert on cell

        return cell
    }

    public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("When cell has been selected")
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Your Custom Cell:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    // attribute example
    let lblCompanyName: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .lightGray
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .bold)
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.6
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    // attribute example
    let lblFrequencies: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .bold)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    // attribute like imageView example
    let imageLogo: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical)
        image.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal)
        return image
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        [imageLogo, lblCompanyName, lblFrequencies].forEach { (view) in contentView.addSubview(view) }

        let top: CGFloat = 20, bottom: CGFloat = -20, leading: CGFloat = 20, trailing: CGFloat = -20

        self.imageLogo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: top).isActive = true
        self.imageLogo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: bottom).isActive = true
        self.imageLogo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: leading).isActive = true
        self.imageLogo.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageLogo.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        self.lblCompanyName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: top).isActive = true
        self.lblCompanyName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.imageLogo.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        self.lblCompanyName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: trailing).isActive = true

        self.lblFrequencies.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.lblCompanyName.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        self.lblFrequencies.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.imageLogo.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        self.lblFrequencies.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: trailing).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Hope it helped you. Cheers.